# product list in category use unknown template

Tags: php, html, magento, templates, magento-1.9

In an example category, the result products are listed using an unknown template. I have pagayo electronics theme as default.It uses a class called item-review and item-bottom for listing. they aren't in html code.
code is like this:

```
<ul class="products-grid">
                <li class="item first">
            <a href="http://magicfly.ir/mentalism/13-steps-to-mentalism.html" title="13 Steps to Mentalism" class="product-image"><img src="http://magicfly.ir/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/3/13steps2.jpg" width="135" height="135" alt="13 Steps to Mentalism" /></a>
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="http://magicfly.ir/mentalism/13-steps-to-mentalism.html" title="13 Steps to Mentalism">13 Steps to Mentalism</a></h2>
                                <div class="ratings">
            <span class="amount"><a href="#" onclick="var t = opener ? opener.window : window; t.location.href='http://magicfly.ir/review/product/list/id/10/category/15/'; return false;">1 نظر</a></span>
</div>



<div class="price-box">
                                                            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-10">
                                        <span class="price">30٬000 تومان</span>                                    </span>

    </div>

                            <div class="actions">

                                                        <p><button type="button" title="افزودن به سبد" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocationAjax('http://magicfly.ir/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL21hZ2ljZmx5LmlyL21lbnRhbGlzbS5odG1s/product/10/form_key/Ql6smZ0IvKikUDgX/','10')"><span><span>افزودن به سبد</span></span></button></p>

                                                                                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                                                        <li><a href="#" onclick='ajaxWishlist("http://magicfly.ir/wishlist/index/add/product/10/form_key/Ql6smZ0IvKikUDgX/","10");return false;' class="link-wishlist">افزودن به لیست دلخواه</a></li>
                                                                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#" onclick='ajaxCompare("http://magicfly.ir/catalog/product_compare/add/product/10/uenc/aHR0cDovL21hZ2ljZmx5LmlyL21lbnRhbGlzbS5odG1s/form_key/Ql6smZ0IvKikUDgX/","10");return false;' class="link-compare">افزودن به مقایسه</a></li>

                    </ul>
```

while it should be like this (wrap with item-review and item-bottom classes):

```
<ul class="products-grid first odd">
                <li class="item first">
                            <a href="http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/accessories/apple-tv.html" title="Apple TV" class="product-image"><img src="http://demo.pagayo.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/p/apple-tv-1.jpg" alt="Apple TV" height="210" width="210"></a>
            <div class="item-review">
                                                                            </div>
            <div class="item-bottom">
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/accessories/apple-tv.html" title="Apple TV">Apple TV</a></h2>



<div class="price-box">
                                                        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-9">
                                        <span class="price">$99.00</span>                                    </span>

    </div>

                <div class="actions">
                                                <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2RlbW8ucGFnYXlvLmNvbS9wYWdheW90aGVtZTAwMS9hY2Nlc3Nvcmllcy5odG1s/product/9/')"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
                                        </div>
            </div>

        </li>
                                <li class="item">
                            <a href="http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/accessories/bose-sounddock-portable-digital-music-system.html" title="Bose SoundDock Portable Digital Music System" class="product-image"><img src="http://demo.pagayo.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/_/4.jpg" alt="Bose SoundDock Portable Digital Music System" height="210" width="210"></a>
            <div class="item-review">
                                            <div class="ratings">
                <div class="rating-box">
            <div class="rating" style="width:97%"></div>
        </div>
            <span class="amount"><a href="#" onclick="var t = opener ? opener.window : window; t.location.href='http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/review/product/list/id/22/category/13/'; return false;">2 Review(s)</a></span>
</div>
                                </div>
            <div class="item-bottom">
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/accessories/bose-sounddock-portable-digital-music-system.html" title="Bose SoundDock Portable Digital Music System">Bose SoundDock Portable Digital Music System</a></h2>



<div class="price-box">
                                                        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-22">
                                        <span class="price">$399.95</span>                                    </span>

    </div>

                <div class="actions">
                                                <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2RlbW8ucGFnYXlvLmNvbS9wYWdheW90aGVtZTAwMS9hY2Nlc3Nvcmllcy5odG1s/product/22/')"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
                                        </div>
            </div>

        </li>
                                <li class="item last">
                            <a href="http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/accessories/bose-soundlink-bluetooth-mobile-speaker-ii.html" title="Bose SoundLink Bluetooth Mobile speaker II" class="product-image"><img src="http://demo.pagayo.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/210x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/_/1.jpg" alt="Bose SoundLink Bluetooth Mobile speaker II" height="210" width="210"></a>
            <div class="item-review">
                                                                            </div>
            <div class="item-bottom">
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/accessories/bose-soundlink-bluetooth-mobile-speaker-ii.html" title="Bose SoundLink Bluetooth Mobile speaker II">Bose SoundLink Bluetooth Mobile speaker II</a></h2>



<div class="price-box">
                                                        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-21">
                                        <span class="price">$349.95</span>                                    </span>

    </div>

                <div class="actions">
                                                <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2RlbW8ucGFnYXlvLmNvbS9wYWdheW90aGVtZTAwMS9hY2Nlc3Nvcmllcy5odG1s/product/21/')"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
                                        </div>
            </div>

        </li>
            </ul>
```

in

> /app/design/frontend/default/pagayo-theme-001/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

it is correctly wrapped but it seems it uses another theme that doesn't wrap it.
I didn't specify custom template for category or any product.
The amazing thing here is I checked list.phtml of base template and copied pagayo list.phtml to base. Just nothing happened.

I want it to use the default theme I specified in configuration Or at least find the phtml file of this piece of code to edit and make it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without seeing its had to infer solution. possibilities are:

1) There can be an issue of improperly selected Magento Package.
system->configuration->Design->Package
2) If you want to see which template using on Template Path hints
system->configuration-> Developer -> Debug -> Template Path Hints select to on 
clear cache and refresh the page.

Comment: I changed theme to rwd and here's the picture of it: http://www.axgig.com/images/80337361512152282429.png it's mixed up and not important what the theme is. I don't know if it is against the rule if I get you the site or not...

Comment: change package to base & Themes-default to your_custom_theme

Comment: http://magicfly.ir/mentalism.html with "base" package and others to mycustomtheme. when there's default instead of base it works correct but the only problem is that product box in category.

Comment: send me username/Password for admin via email:
hassanalishahzad@yahoo.com

Comment: thanks for the great job. He solved the problem. It was about an extension called ajaxsuit that has list.phtml file conflicting with the original one.